# Different colorisation for global variable and local mutable variable?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

In vscode, variables declared with let and variables declared with const are colorized differently. Yet there is no distinction between local and global variables. Is there a way to change the highlighting so I know the variable I am looking at is a global / module wide variable instead of a variable declared somewhere within the local function?

I am using the theme dark modern.

[image: Syntax Highlighting Example]

Comment: `let` and `const` declarations are the same color for me. What theme are you using?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "global" exactly? This can be tricky and misleading. For example, declaring with `var`, `let`, or `const` at the top level of a function makes no difference in terms of visibility.

Comment: Added image for clarification.

Comment: I see, it seems only Light Modern and Dark Modern are doing this. Various other themes (including Monokai that I'm using) don't differentiate between the two. Either way, there are ways to customize themes, have you looked into [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme)?

Comment: "_the variable I am looking at is a global / module wide variable instead of a variable declared somewhere within the local function_" [there is another](https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/001/590/365/d50.jpg): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures. So what do you want for variables from closures? Just colour them the same as non-"globals"?